# If $P$ violates a liveness property $\phi$, does $P$ have a lasso run $r$ violating $\phi$?

Tags: logic, model-theory, formal-languages, automata

I have seen multiple papers cite [[VW86]](https://orbi.uliege.be/bitstream/2268/116609/1/lics86.pdf) in saying that, for every LTL property $\phi$ and automaton $P$, if $P$ has a run $r$ violating $\phi$, then $P$ also has a run $r' = \alpha \beta^{\omega}$ violating $\phi$, where $r'$ is called a *lasso* and consists of a finite prefix $\alpha$ followed by infinite repetition of a loop $\beta$.  However, I do not see this result anywhere in the cited paper.  (Possibly it is alluded to in discussions of Büchi acceptance conditions?)

Every LTL property is the intersection of an LTL liveness property and an LTL safety property [[MMD14]](http://people.inf.ethz.ch/basin/pubs/ipl14.pdf).  If $P$ violates the safety property then the proof is straightforward: find the bad prefix $\alpha$, and then prove there must exist a run beginning with $\alpha$ and then looping forever after some time, arguing according to the finitude of the structure (assuming we only allow finite-state machines).

But what if the property is a liveness property?  Although I intuitively understand why an LTL property cannot *only* be violated by a non-lasso run like $a b a a b a a a b a a a a b a a a a a b ...$, I do not mathematically understand why this is the case.

Comment: I now understand that the classical proof, alluded to in Pin's answer, involves constructing a Büchi automaton and then arguing based on the acceptance condition for the existence of a lasso run in that automaton.  You can remove all but one loop in this manner, and then you get a lasso; $\blacksquare$.  Possibly this can be alternatively proven without automata, using only language theory; I don't know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The language of infinite words defined by a LTL property is [$\omega$-regular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omega-regular_language). The complement of a $\omega$-regular language is also $\omega$-regular. Thus the set of $\omega$-words violating a LTL-formula is $\omega$-regular.
Finally, every nonempty $\omega$-regular language contains an ultimately periodic word, that is, a word of the form $uv^\omega$ for some finite words $u$ and $v$.

Comment: Dr. Pin, thank you for answering!  I learned formal language theory from your book!  It’s an honor :)